# gotomypc and aircard?

Tags: remote-desktop, aircard

My boss is looking at getting an aircard ( internet over cell network ) for his laptop. One of the uses he mentioned was gotomypc. I couldn't find good information on it, but I was thinking it would blow out the bandwidth because it was like streaming a movie. Is gotomypc really feasible with an aircard at this point?

Answer (score 1):

Most aircards have monthly throughput caps (Verizon is, or recently was, 5 Gb, I think), with a charge for every extra Mb over. If your boss is going to use GoToMyPC a lot, he's probably gonna go over each month. However, all those cards come with software that track bytes in and out, so you could teach him how to monitor his usage.

Comment: We'd like to figure out if we can afford this before we sign up, find out it's too expensive, and cancel it. We don't have an aircard already.